# Finding a general solution for $u_{xx}-4u_{xy}+3u_{yy}=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $$u_{xx}-4u_{xy}+3u_{yy}=0.$$  Find the general solution given the solution $u(x,y)=f(\lambda x+y).$

My attempt was as follows:  let $u(x,y)=e^{\lambda x+y}$.  Then by computing $u_{xx},u_{xy}, \text{ and } u_{yy}$ we get $e^{\lambda x+y}(\lambda^2-4\lambda+3).$  This shows us that $\lambda =1$ or $\lambda =3$.

Is this the right track?

Comment: You should not take a **specific** function $e^{\lambda x+y}$: in other words, just take $u(x,y)=f(\lambda x+y)$ as given.  You should find that $u_{xx}$ etc are equally easy as what you did already, and you get the same values for $\lambda$.

Comment: Then take $t=\lambda x+y$ and you get an ODE after rewriting the x,y derivatives as t derivatives.

Comment: So you mean, for example, $u_{xx}=f_{xx}(\lambda x+y)\lambda^2$ and so forth?  Doesn't the $f_{xx}$ and sort forth complicate factoring?

Comment: Do you know what they mean by the general solution in the question?

Comment: I'm having problems with the terminology.  I've always thought that the solution to a DE consists of a particular and general solution added together.

Comment: Instead of arbitrary constants, general solutions of PDE's may involve arbitrary functions.

Comment: @RobertIsrael what if we take the $u_{xx}$ of $f(\lambda x+y)$? would that work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The idea is that the differential operator $\partial_{xx} - 4 \partial_{xy} + 3 \partial_{yy}$ decomposes as a product of two commuting operators of order $1$:
$$\partial_{xx} - 4 \partial_{xy} + 3 \partial_{yy} = ( \partial_x - \partial_y)(\partial_x - 3 \partial_y)= (\partial_x - 3 \partial_y)( \partial_x - \partial_y)$$
Now for any functions $f$, $g$ in $1$ variable  we have 
$$( \partial_x - \partial_y)( f(x+y) )= 0$$
and 
$$(\partial_x - 3 \partial_y) ( g (3x + y) ) =0$$
Therefore, any function $u$ of form
$$u(x,y) = f(x+y) + g(3x + y)$$
is a solution of the equation. It is not hard to show that in this way we get all the solutions.